# Why is app_process generating an segmentation fault?

Tags: android

I've built AOSP 4.4.3.43 for the first time and can run it in the emulator. However, I can not install apps either from Android Studio, adb, adb shell, or anywhere. I've narrowed the problem down to app_process generating a segmentation fault.

I've seen places where they mention LD_LIBRARY_PATH as being a problem, I have added it to init.environ.rc.in and recompiled. When I run the newly recompiled rom in the emulator I can see that LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib is set correctly (by running cat /proc/$$/environ).

```
10-13 21:38:25.048  1441  1441 D AndroidRuntime: 
10-13 21:38:25.048  1441  1441 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
10-13 21:38:25.079  1441  1441 D AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
10-13 21:38:25.813  1441  1443 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 1443 (JDWP)
10-13 21:38:25.928   304   449 W NativeCrashListener: Couldn't find ProcessRecord for pid 1441
10-13 21:38:25.931    53    53 I DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-13 21:38:25.932    53    53 E DEBUG   : AM write failure (32 / Broken pipe)
10-13 21:38:25.932    53    53 I DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Android/aosp_arm/generic:4.4.3.43.43.43/AOSP/mike10121305:eng/test-keys'
10-13 21:38:25.933    53    53 I DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
10-13 21:38:25.934    53    53 I DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
10-13 21:38:25.937    53    53 I DEBUG   : pid: 1441, tid: 1443, name: JDWP  >>> app_process <<<
10-13 21:38:25.938    53    53 I DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
10-13 21:38:25.957    53    53 I DEBUG   :     r0 b312c040  r1 b30fd76c  r2 00000000  r3 00000001
10-13 21:38:25.958    53    53 I DEBUG   :     r4 000003e8  r5 b30fd7a0  r6 6fe9a390  r7 b30fd7c8
10-13 21:38:25.958    53    53 I DEBUG   :     r8 b54fca6c  r9 b3112400  sl 00000000  fp b30fd7a8
10-13 21:38:25.959    53    53 I DEBUG   :     ip b55730c0  sp b30fd760  lr 71e4ab73  pc 00000000  cpsr 60000010
10-13 21:38:25.963    53    53 I DEBUG   : 
10-13 21:38:25.963    53    53 I DEBUG   : backtrace:
10-13 21:38:25.963    53    53 I DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00000000  <unknown>
10-13 21:38:25.964    53    53 I DEBUG   :     #01 pc 00000b71  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
10-13 21:38:27.613    53    53 I DEBUG   : 
10-13 21:38:27.613    53    53 I DEBUG   : Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_02
10-13 21:38:27.616   304   365 I BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_02 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
10-13 21:38:27.801   304   319 I art     : Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 234(27KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 7MB/7MB, paused 6.504ms total 106.733ms
10-13 21:38:28.222   304   319 I art     : Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 14604(836KB) AllocSpace objects, 12(1648KB) LOS objects, 19% free, 6MB/7MB, paused 2.752ms total 400.518ms
```

I still get the seg fault. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like something wrong early in the life of the jdwp thread, you might see how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Fetch and attach your tombstone file.

`adb pull /data/tombstones/tombstone_02`